# Pojo (with Binding) object is null in 2 way data binding in Android

Tags: data-binding, android-databinding

Below is my xml
[image: activity_login.xml]

Below is my Pojo
[image]

Below is my kotlin class
[image]

I'm always getting null at line 19 of kotlin class for binding.data
I would like to know, when binding.tv1 & binding.et1 are not null, why would binding.data (pojo) be null?

It is working fine if i uncomment lines 16 & 17 of kotlin class & use loginInfo.data instead of binding.data . Why is it not allowing me to use binding.data object without initialising it?

Answer (score 0):

- Uncomment line 16 and 17.
- Add `binding.setLifecycleOwner` and `binding.executePendingBindings`